# FileSystemWatcher - отключение уведомлений, когда приложение не имеет фокуса

Tags: c#, wpf

Пишу редактор со вкладками (c# wpf). Прикрутил FileSystemWatcher для
отслеживания изменения содержимого текстовых файлов во вкладках.
Но не получается сделать так, чтобы уведомление (watcher.Changed)
об изменении файла (внешним процессом) появлялось только тогда, когда
фокус находится на вкладках или хотя бы в фокусе находится главное окно
приложения. И не появлялось, когда мы находимся в окне(ах) другого
приложения. Каким образом народ решает подобные задачи ?

Comment: Ок, а где ваши попытки решить задачу? Ведь каждый контрол имеет свойство фокуса, как и само окно, что мешает привязаться и использовать дальше где надо это свойство? Ну или на худой конец `if (window.IsFocused){ //Оповещаем }`, если у вас там конечно нет MVVM, привязок и прочего (что зря).

Answer (score 1):

Решил задачу просто. Настраиваю свой 'флаг' в обработчиках Window.Activated 'флаг=true' и Window.Deactivated 'флаг=false'. В обработчике события 'watcher.Changed' в начале проверяю 'флаг' while(!флаг){}. Т.е. по приходе события 'Changes', если окно приложения не в фокусе, то просто тупо ждём, пока окно примет фокус.